# Define scale manually in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to set y scale by myself. For example, I have a following plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 500, 10)
y = np.random.randint(low = 10, high = 100, size = 50)
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to set x axis as "0 10 20 30 40 50" on the position of "0 100 200 300 400 500" although I know the x value is not like that. I have tried to  define xticks but the x axis become very narrow.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 50, 10))
```

[image]

How can I achieve this without changing x value? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for `xticks`, it can take a `ticks` and a `labels`. Just provide correct values for the locations, and then place a labels array:

```py
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,501,100), np.arange(0, 51, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set x axis limit by `xlim`, and `ylim` for y axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 500, 10)
y = np.random.randint(low = 10, high = 100, size = 50)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim([0,50]) #set range for x axis
plt.show()
```